# Como remover o espaçamento das colunas em bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

Boa tarde a todos, estou trabalhando com colunas e me deparei com um problema que está me batendo a muito tempo, como podem observar neste exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/qt542gLo/, preciso que a "Box 3" e também a "Box 5" não estejam lá embaixo, quero que os elementos do lado esquerdo não sejam afetados pela altura dos elementos do lado oposto. Tentei por várias formas ajustar a margin mas não está funcionando, agradeço desde já!.

Comment: Você tenque rever o `layout` da página, pois sua box grande está quebrando-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu layout está estourando as colunas do bootstrap, a soma de todos os tamanhos das colunas precisa ser igual a 12, sendo assim, você precisa definir quantas colunas seu layout terá, se forem duas colunas, a composição deve ser feita com duas divs com "col-xx-6" (onde xx deve ser substituido por md, xs, etc), se o layout tiver 3 colunas, use três divs com "col-xx-4" e assim por diante, você pode conferir um exemplo com duas colunas [neste plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IIzj6qEQyMUjw14bJhli).

Mais informações você pode obter direto do site do Bootstrap [neste link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).